# announcing rtsp. A way to overcome blocked ports?

Tags: android, video-streaming, firewall, rtsp, ip-camera

If all incoming ports are blocked on a ip camera (due to cellular network stuff), is it possible to have the ip camera initiate the connection to the client-viewer?

I am looking at using a android phone as a ip camera, (there are plenty of examples for the rtsp portion) but will need to figure out how to control the phone from the client-viewer using control connection initiated by the phone itself.

Would SDP announce work?

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, you need an RTSP server, which can accept announcements from the IP camera, and relay the RTP streams from the IP camera to the RTSP client.
Otherwise, the RTSP client cannot reach the Ip camera directly.

Comment: so, from the ip camera I send an rtsp announce, which gets the client ready for the rtp packets pushed by the ip camera?

Comment: yes, you are right. The ip cameras should keep rtsp connection with the server, and wait for client access.

Comment: is there some IP camera that can do this (be a client only)?